# Visit counter for anonymous visits?

Tags: 7, sessions

I would like to keep track of the number of visits for each anonymous user. I want to be able to show special messages, for example when they visit the site the 10th time.

Incrementing a cookie variable will just be fine in this case. How do I find out when a new session has started?

Comment: for reference I got a good answer on: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9106720/keep-track-of-visit-count-in-php-cookie

Answer (score 1):

This would be difficult I believe, because every anonymous visitor is essentially treated as the same, as one account.

Answer (score 0):

You are most likely best to make use of [session_api module](http://drupal.org/project/session_api) and some custom moduling.

Comment: Session may be cleared when user leaves the site.

Answer (score 0):

Needed functions are readily described in manual:
http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!user!user.module/function/user_cookie_save/7

Don't forget to respect [Do Not Track](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Do_Not_Track) or you risk a lawsuit in some jurisdictions.